# PHP: change a method behavior

Tags: php, oop

I have an object with some protected fields and a method that uses them. The method doesn't do exactly what I need it to do, but I cannot change the original code since I am writing an add-on. 
Is it somehow possible to extend the class and override the method so that I could call it on predefined objects of the original class? I thought about monkey patching but apparently it is not implemented in php.

Comment: It depends... if the original class is autoloaded via a registered autoloader maybe you can create your own class and autoloader and force the autoload chain to go through your autoloader first. If you're using a framework maybe you should check if it allows this natively (Laravel for example offers a great deal of support on doing this). Overall there's not nearly enough information here to help.

Comment: I was trying to make up a mock up example, but the project structure is so convoluted with toms of nested classes that it is difficult to decide which parts are relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override a method by extending the parent class, initiating the new class instead of the parent class and naming your method exactly the same as the parent method, that was the child method will be called and not the parent

Example:

```
class Foo {
    function sayFoo() {
        echo "Foo";
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    function sayFoo() {
        echo "Bar";
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$bar = new Bar();

$foo->sayFoo() //Outputs: Foo
$bar->sayFoo() //Outputs: Bar
```

Comment: In my case initiation happens somewhere else, unfortunately

Comment: Then no you cannot overwrite a method without changing the initiation of the class.

Comment: Well you can use [runkit](https://pecl.php.net/package/runkit) for this. But you might run into unexpected behavior of some other methods that use the method you are going to replace.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to change it only for my purposes, not globally.

Comment: I would steer clear of runkit, also it does not yet support PHP7 [ISSUE #87](https://github.com/zenovich/runkit/issues/87)

Comment: I think I am going to extend the classes that instantiate the object in my case, then it should be possible to do what I need. Thank you for making a clear example!

Answer (score 0):

I hope below stategy will be works. asume that class is `Foo` and method is `bar()`. for override `bar()` method you have to make `customFoo` class as mentioned below.

```
class CustomFoo extends Foo{
    public function bar(){
        parent::bar();
    } 
}
```

I dont know actually what you need because you dont have explained in detail. Still I have tried my best. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a child class that extends the base or parent class that the object currently derives from. 
Create a new method with exactly the same name as the method in the Parent class and put your logic in there.
Now instantiate your object from your new class, you would have succeeded in overriding that particular method and still have access to the methods and properties of the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, once you've loaded the class, you can't officially unload it, and you do need to load it in order to extend it. So it's pretty tied up. Your best bet is to either hack the original class (not ideal) or copy paste the original class definition into a new file:

```
class ParentClass {
      //Copy paste code and modify as you need to.
}
```

Somewhere after the bootstrapping of your framework:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
      if ($class == "ParentClass") { //Namespace is also included in the class name so adjust accordingly
         include 'path/to/modified/ParentClass.php';
      }
},true,true);
```

This is done to ensure your own modified class will be loaded before the original one. 
This is extremely hacky so first check if the framework you're using has native support for doing this.

Comment: Will this affect also all other things that can use this class?

Comment: Yes, but this solution is not ideal. Only use it if your really really really don't have any other option.